# Prepared statements & select, 0 rows found

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Alright so my problem is simple, Im trying to get results from a query but it always returns that there are no users registered with the username.

```
<?php 
    require "assembly/oop/sql_classbuild.php";

    class player {
        private $name;
        private $age;
        private $gender;
        private $location;

        public function createNew($name, $age, $gender, $location) {

            $conni = new sql();
            $conn = $conni->connect();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO players (name, age, gender, location) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("siss", $name, $age, $gender, $location);

            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age; 
            $this->gender = $gender;
            $this->location = $location;

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }

        public function isRegistered($name) { //problematic code

            $conni = new sql();
            $conn = $conni->connect();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM players WHERE name=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->num_rows >= 1) { //if there is a registered member
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                return false;
            }
        }

    }



?>
```

Now I also tried to print num_rows but it just returns 0 as if there are no results inside the DB. 
The usage is quite simple

```
if($player->isRegistered("Test") == true) {
        echo "Hello";
    }
    else {
        echo "Non-existing user";
    }
```

SQL screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMqub.jpg
Also this is the sql class pastebin.com/Evg13CUc

Comment: So I tested it once again and num_rows returns 0. I tried printing the query but the query seems fine..

Comment: I cannot see why it wouldn't work. Clearly I don't have all the information you have. So I have to assume that the name 'Test' occurs in the database, and all the stuff that's not in the code actually works correctly. You will have to try to debug. Try to run the query outside your code, for instance in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Well I just ran it in my phpmyadmin and I got the correct results.
SELECT playerid FROM players WHERE name='Toma'

Comment: Also this is the sql class http://pastebin.com/Evg13CUc

Comment: Again, I cannot verify what you did, all I can see is that `SELECT playerid FROM players WHERE name='Toma'` is not the same as `SELECT name FROM players WHERE name='Test'`. I suggest trying it with 'Test' instead of 'Toma'.

Comment: Yeah I get where you are coming from, altho I think its something else (I used Toma since I truncated the table before that & inserted Toma in it). My idea is that it requires ' ' instead of " ". I mean like WHERE name='Toma' while with the query it will just name=Toma right? Maybe its different in PHP or such. http://imgur.com/a/TXqiJ because my way of thinking is, name=? wont be name='Toma', it will just be name=Toma

Comment: No, you don't need the quotes in prepared statements. In the `bind_param()` function you indicate that it's a string, and that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved.
I used $stmt->store_result(); which somehow worked out and it gave me the good results.